# COCOS2d CCLabelTTF not updating with player score - using a CCLayer Class

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I would be very grateful for any advice you can offer as I am growing increasingly frustrated with an issue I am having - I also appreciate that the issue I am having is due to my lack of knowledge / understanding.

In an attempt to further my knowledge and stretch myself, I have chosen to create a PlayerStats class that handles the players scoring - and in time, health, etc.

I have the GameLevelLayer and PlayerStats classes implemented as follows:

GameLevelLayer.m as follows:

```
#import "GameLevelLayer.h"
#import "Player.h"
#import "PlayerStats.h"

@interface GameLevelLayer() {
  CCTMXTiledMap *map;
  Player *player;
  PlayerStats *playerStats;
}

@end

@implementation GameLevelLayer

@synthesize grabber = _grabber;

+(CCScene *) scene
{
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];
    GameLevelLayer *layer = [GameLevelLayer node];
    PlayerStats *hudLayer = [PlayerStats node];

   [scene addChild: layer];
   [scene addChild: hudLayer];

return scene;
}

-(id) init {

if( (self=[super init]) ) {

    CGSize screenSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

    playerStats = [[PlayerStats alloc]init];
    ...........
   }
```

PlayerStats.m is as follows:

```
-(id) init
   {
     if ((self = [super init])) {

     CGSize screenSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
     score = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Score : 0" dimensions:CGSizeMake(100,20) hAlignment:UITextAlignmentRight fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:(18.0)];

     int margin = 5;

     score.position = ccp(screenSize.width - (score.contentSize.width/2) - margin, score.contentSize.height/2 + margin);

     [self addChild:score z:99];
   }
     return self;
 }

-(void)numberOfItemsCollected:(int)collected {

    NSString *str = [score string];
    CCLOG(@"What does the label say %@", str);
    // This is actually displaying the correct string of what the score should be .. 

    [score setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score : %d", collected]];


}
```

When (from the GameLevelLayer.m) I initiate

```
 [playerStats numberOfItemsCollected:5];
```

the CCLog shows that the label should show Score : 5 but the label itself does not update.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated as I am very aware that I am misunderstanding the issue.
I think the issue is to do with the Layer that I am updating not being the one I believe it is....

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code looks fine, and I do something nearly identical to what you're doing. What does the label actually display?  No text? Or just "Score : 0"?  Try stepping into the cocos2d code and see what happens inside `setString:`

Comment: The label shows Score: 0 .. while the Log shows "What does the label say Score : 5" for example ..

Comment: I'm at a loss. I guess double check you aren't accidentally sending the wrong value for `collected`. You should add a CCLog to print the value after calling `[score setString:...`, and add printing `collected`'s value directly to the CCLog as well.

Comment: It was indeed me being stupid.  I had declared CCLabelTTF *score as an instance variable of the PlayerStats Class.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I had declared the CCLabelTTF *score as an instance variable in the PlayerStats Class header.  What a difference a night away from code makes.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I managed to solve this issue set string to an empty string then reSet it to your string

```
[label setString:@""];
[label setString:yourString];
```